# How To Remove Duplicate Rows By Column's Value in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have the data frame below

```
    Email          | Action   | Time 
    -------------- | -------- | -------------------
    a@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-11 08:50:59
    b@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-11 08:51:42
    a@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-11 08:55:13 -> this is duplicate data
    a@mydomain.com | checkout | 2016-07-11 19:15:20
    c@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-12 08:58:20
    a@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-12 09:15:00
    c@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-12 09:20:13 -> this is duplicate data
    a@mydomain.com | checkout | 2016-07-12 20:20:10
```

I need to remove the duplicate rows with the same action value (for this case are `checkin` and `checkout`) within the same date (`YYYY-MM-DD`). It should be like this:

```
    Email          | Action   | Time 
    -------------- | -------- | -------------------
    a@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-11 08:50:59
    b@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-11 08:51:42
    a@mydomain.com | checkout | 2016-07-11 19:15:20
    c@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-12 08:58:20
    a@mydomain.com | checkin  | 2016-07-12 09:15:00
    a@mydomain.com | checkout | 2016-07-12 20:20:10
```

I know I can `substr` the Time column to get the `YYYY-MM-DD`, but I don't have any idea how to remove the duplicate rows. Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Do not use string processing functions for this. Use `as.POSIXct` and `as.Date`.

Comment: Ah thanks. You're right, I can use `as.Date` to get the date. Now, I need to find a way to remove the duplicate data. I had tried `duplicated` but the result is not what I intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a column called `Days` to keep dates in the format `YYYY-d-m`. Then use the combination of `Email`, `Action` and `Days` to find the duplicates and remove them.

```
##Create the column
flights_info$Days <- as.POSIXct(strftime(flights_info$Time, format = "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"), format="%Y-%d-%m")

##Remove the duplicates
flights_info[!duplicated(flights_info[,c("Email","Action","Days")]),]
```

Desired output:

```
Email          Action   Time                Days      
 a@mydomain.com checkin  2016-07-11 08:50:59 2016-07-11
 b@mydomain.com checkin  2016-07-11 08:51:42 2016-07-11
 a@mydomain.com checkout 2016-07-11 19:15:20 2016-07-11
 c@mydomain.com checkin  2016-07-12 08:58:20 2016-07-12
 a@mydomain.com checkin  2016-07-12 09:15:00 2016-07-12
 a@mydomain.com checkout 2016-07-12 20:20:10 2016-07-12
```

If you wish not to have the `Days` column anymore, you can remove it with:

```
flights_info[!duplicated(flights_info[,c("Email","Action","Days")]),-ncol(flights_info)]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Cool! It works, but It should be bound to the new data frame like this `new_flight_info <-flights_info[!duplicated(flights_info[,c("Email","Action","Days")]),-ncol(flights_info)]`

I don't know why...

Comment: @AsepBagjaPriandana, you can name the output whatever name you see fit. As long as the data is what you want, the name is subjective.